# How to seach Directory files which contain the string starting with @"anystring"&#x9

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have xml files  in c:/dom/xml .
I just want to search all the xml files containg the text or string start
with @"anystring"&#x9

Example:
the below tag is presented in xml file i need to filter the xml file name that containg the text.

`<parameter ID="**@Id_name&#x9**;&#x9;" >`

I tried below

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceFolder = @"C:\dom\Xml";
        string searchWord = "&#x9";

        List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
        AddFileNamesToList(sourceFolder, allFiles);
        foreach (string fileName in allFiles)
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            if (contents.Contains(searchWord))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void AddFileNamesToList(string sourceDir, List<string> allFiles)
    {

        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            allFiles.Add(fileName);
        }

        //Recursion    
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir);
        foreach (string item in subdirectoryEntries)
        {
            // Avoid "reparse points"
            if ((File.GetAttributes(item) & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
            {
                AddFileNamesToList(item, allFiles);
            }
        }

    }
```

But i need serchword like '@"Anystring"&#x9'

Comment: What you have tried so far? Kindly put your effort in your question.

Comment: replace the `string searchWord = "&Anystring#x9";`

Comment: Will it filter <parameter ID="**@Id_name&#x9**;&#x9;" >?

Comment: It would be awesome if the example text you provided `<parameter ID="**@Id_name&#x9**;&#x9;" >` actually matched the template `@"anystring"&#x9` you've asked for. They **don't** match. I get that the `anystring` part means any string, but they still don't match. Can you please fix that?

Comment: Can you please provide a larger example set of the text you need to match?

Comment: I have dom.xml file.which contain the text " <parameter ID="@dominic$#x9"... I need to fileter this xml

Comment: Can we use any Regex or string pattern to math that case?

Comment: I hope ,  @([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).\&#x9 , this Regex helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope below code will help you.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceFolder = @"C:\dom";
        string searchWord = "&#x9";            
        string regexPattern = @"@([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).\&#x9";


        List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
        AddFileNamesToList(sourceFolder, allFiles);
        foreach (string fileName in allFiles)
        {
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
            if (showMatch(contents, regexPattern))
            {
                if (contents.Contains(searchWord))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(fileName);
                }
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static bool showMatch(string text, string expr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Expression: " + expr);
        MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);
        foreach (Match m in mc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(m);
        }
        return mc.Count > 0;
    }

    public static void AddFileNamesToList(string sourceDir, List<string> allFiles)
    {

        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
        foreach (string fileName in fileEntries)
        {
            allFiles.Add(fileName);
        }

        //Recursion    
        string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir);
        foreach (string item in subdirectoryEntries)
        {
            // Avoid "reparse points"
            if ((File.GetAttributes(item) & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
            {
                AddFileNamesToList(item, allFiles);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define [`Regex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx) as below and use it in your code.

```
 Regex rule = new Regex(@"(\\ |[^ ])+\$#x9\b");
```

The code can be modify to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string sourceFolder = @"C:\dom\Xml";
    string searchWord = @"(\\ |[^ ])+\$#x9\b";
    Regex rule = new Regex(searchWord);

    List<string> allFiles = new List<string>();
    AddFileNamesToList(sourceFolder, allFiles);
    foreach (string fileName in allFiles)
    {
        string contents = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
        if (rule.IsMatch(contents))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fileName);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(" ");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Working fiddler [`demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZHHYyn)